# iOS change UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app I have a gradient as a background. This gradient is made programmatically. The way that I now use this is like this:

I have a `UIViewController` which needs to display the gradient and in that class I do this :

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [Gradient gradientInViewController:self];
}
```

This ain't so bad but this needs to be done in all the classes which isn't very good programming. What I want is instead of making a class a `UIViewController`, I want it to be a `GradientViewController` which is a subclass of `UIViewController` and in this class I will handle everything.

So my question is how do I do this? I think this has to be done through categories? But I can't figure out how to get the image on the screen. Should this be done in viewWillAppear or something?

Comment: simply change [super viewDidAppear:animated]; to [super viewDidAppear:animated];

Comment: @NANNAV not sure what the difference is between them did you mean to say `[super viewWillAppea:animated];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a `GradientViewController` which handles the gradient drawing

```
@interface GradientViewController : UIViewController

@end

@implementation GradientViewController

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [Gradient gradientInViewController:self];
}

@end
```

Then inherit all your other controllers from that

```
@interface YourViewController : GradientViewController

@end

@implementation YourViewController

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // no need to do anything
}

@end
```

It's more flexible to do it through helper classes or categories though, even if there's a bit of repetition.

Note as pointed out by Nguyen Duc, that you are calling `[super viewDidAppear:]` for `viewWillAppear:` which is wrong, I edited the answer.

Comment: I will give you the best answer since it gives an entire explanation! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Interface Builder and have a xib that knows how to load your image for you automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new view controller (let's call it `GradientViewController` for example), put the same code that draws the gradient into its view `viewWillAppear`, then make all your view controllers a subclass of the view controller by replacing

```
@interface SomeViewController : UIViewController
```

with

```
@interface SomeViewController : GradientViewController
```

Comment: Thank you! Just realized I completely overthought this!

Answer (score 0):

You can get this behaviour "for free" throughout your app simply by subclassing UIViewController:-

```
@interface GradientViewController : UIViewController 
@end
```

and implementing your gradient code in `viewDidLoad:` as such:-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [Gradient gradientInViewController:self];
}
```

Then just use GradientViewController instead of UIViewController everywhere you need your gradient.

Alternatively you can use a category. This can be useful because you can use categories for "themes" for your app, configuring various UI elements of your `UIViewController`s. But I'd set up a category on `UIViewController` specifically to set your gradient, and then call the category method in every view controller that needs it - do **not** attempt to do it by overriding `viewDidLoad:` or  `viewWillAppear:` in a category.